# RxJS 6 websocket does not receive any message

Tags: websocket, rxjs

I am testing out rxjs websocket with sample code below, but when I try to publish from https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, I couldn't receive any message on the HTML, is this expected? How can I subscribe to topic from https://www.websocket.org/echo.html?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.2.2/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
        const { WebSocketSubject } = rxjs.webSocket;
        const socket$ = new WebSocketSubject('wss://echo.websocket.org');
        socket$.subscribe(
                (data) => console.log(data),
                (err) => console.error(err),
                () => console.warn('Completed!')
            );
        console.log('here')
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's an echo websocket, so don't you have to send it a message to echo first?

Comment: Yes I did the pub from https://www.websocket.org/echo.html and attempt to subscribe from my code.

Comment: I don't see you sending a message to the websocket in your code though. The echo is only for a specific client-server pair you can't publish from their website and receive it on your local host.

Comment: Yes after few days of testing I realized it is not broadcast but server-client pair. I have configured my local server for testing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

websocket.org/echo.html does not offer broadcast thus using it for local testing will not receive any reply.

Running a local websocket server for testing is the way to go.